# Symfony2 http_basic security rejects valid credentials

Tags: security, symfony, basic-authentication

I use Symfony Standard 2.0.0BETA1 and tried to configure http_basic authentication exactly the same as in [this book chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security/overview.html#configuration)

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

providers:
    main:
        users:
            foo: { password: testing, roles: ROLE_USER }

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    /.*
        http_basic: true
        logout:     true

access_control:
    - { path: /.*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Problem is when I try to open a page and i submit user name "foo" and password "testing" it simply loops and ask me for credential infinitely or display error page.

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Copy security configuration from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security/overview.html#configuration and past it to security.yml file
2. Refresh app home page
3. Enter valid credentials

Expected behavior is to see home page but instead credentials prompt is shown.

Does anyone know why that happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The http basic authentication is broken with PHP as cgi/fastCGI under Apache

There is a workaround:

**app_dev.php**

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) )
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && (strlen($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) > 0))
    {
        list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
        if( strlen($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) == 0 || strlen($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) == 0 )
        {
            unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
            unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
        }
    }
}
```

**web/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Source: [symfony github issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1813)**

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you restricted access to `/.*`, which means all paths, to only users who have the role ROLE_USER.

Say your login path is `/login`, the user tries to access any other path and is redirected to the login path. The login path (`/login`) will be matched by the access control pattern `/.*`. The user will then be denied of access because he doesn't have the role ROLE_USER right now. The security component will redirect the user again to the login form so he can authenticate to get the role, which is restricted, and will redirect the user to the login form to authenticate and so on.

Here's a simple solution to avoid this problem. You can allow access to the login form to anonymous user with the activation of the anonymous user configuration and a new access control item. Add this below `main` in the `firewalls` configuration to enable anonymous user:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous: true
```

And add a new access control item to allow anonymous user to acces the `/login` pattern:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /.*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

The order is important here since the rule is: first path matched wins. So the `/login` path must be above your pattern for other path `/.*`. This should resolves you redirect loop.

The documentation of Symfony about security is being rewritten right now and will talk more in details about this problem. It is in the [symfony-docs](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs) github repository under the [security](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/tree/security) branch.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: OK, I see your point, but I'm trying to use HTTP basic, so no custom login forms, browser should automatically display credentials form (or, by standard, I could access my app by simply setting appropriate headers, something like `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`)

Comment: +1 this was driving me crazy, I'm using 2.1, the docs say nothing about this.

Answer (score 7):

The same problem still occurs in the current version (Symfony version 2.1.8).

It's because of the special way that Apache + PHP as FastCGI handles HTTP auth variables.

At least, the fix for the current version is a little simplier than it was before (as compared to  @Teo.sk's answer), and the instructions are available directly hardcoded as comments in the file `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php` of the framework:

```
/*
* php-cgi under Apache does not pass HTTP Basic user/pass to PHP by default
* For this workaround to work, add these lines to your .htaccess file:
* RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
* RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
*
* A sample .htaccess file:
* RewriteEngine On
* RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
* RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
* RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
* RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
*/
```

In short, to fix it, all you have to do is to add the following lines to the `.htaccess` file of the `web/` folder of your application:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

**New info (2013-05-01)**: now I'm using Symfony version 2.2.1 and for the fix to work I had to add those two lines of codes right below the following line of `web/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: This is exactly what fixed my problem. I already found the RewriteRule somewhere else on stackoverflow but it only worked after i added the RewriteCond. Thanks!

Comment: shortest and most up-to-date solution here.

Answer (score 1):

you dont't need to modify your  SymfonyProject, you need also change apache2 configuration.

sudoedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/[your site].conf

insert

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

keep to restart apache2

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

i use my boundle route:

```
 - { path: /correspondencia/recepcion/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
 - { path: /correspondencia/recepcion, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

without the last slash
wrong

```
/correspondencia/recepcion/
```

good

```
/correspondencia/recepcion
```